# How do I replace divs on click using jQuery (comment system)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replace the ".comment" div with the ".edit-form" div on the click of the "edit-comment" button. Things are working, but not exactly the way I want them to. There is one little problem: when I click on any "edit button" of the primary unordered list (inside list item), and then I click on the "edit button" of the secondary unordered list, the ".comment" div of the primary unordered list hides/disappears, but I don't want that to happen, I want it to show and not to be influenced by the "edit-comment" button effect in the secondary list, if at all you understand me. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //$(document).on('click' , '.reply' , function(){
  $('.reply').click(function(){
     var closestDiv = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent()
     $('.reply-to-comment').not(closestDiv.find('.reply-to-comment')).css("display", "none");
     closestDiv.find('.reply-to-comment').slideToggle(100);
  });

  //$(document).on('click' , '.edit-comment' , function(){
  $('.edit-comment').click(function(){ 
     var closestDivtwo = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent()
     $('.edit-form').not(closestDivtwo.find('.edit-form')).css('display', 'none');
     closestDivtwo.find('.edit-form').slideToggle(100);
     //$(this).next('.edit-form').slideToggle(100);
  });

  //$(document).on('click' , '.edit-comment' , function(){
  $('.edit-comment').click(function(){ 
     var closestDivtwo = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent()
     //$('.comment').not(closestDivtwo.find('.comment')).fadeOut();
     //closestDivtwo.find('.comment').css('display','block');
     closestDivtwo.find('.comment').toggle();
     //$('.comment').not(closestDivtwo.find('.comment')).slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

Just concentrate on the second and third, let's say, paragraph of this snippet. This is my HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Test it!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul class="list-of-comments">
<div class="allcomments">
    <li class="noofcomments">
        <div class="comment-wrap">
            <div class="commentator-pic"></div>
            <div class="comment">Comments show here</div>
            <!--This is the position of the edit form-->
            <div class="edit-form">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                    <textarea class="subcomment" name="subcomment" cols="50" rows="4">Edit comment</textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <!--These are the main comment buttons or controllers-->
            <button class="edit-comment">Edit</button>
            <button class="reply">Reply</button>
            <button>Delete</button>
            <!--This is the position of the reply form-->
            <div class="reply-to-comment">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                    <textarea class="subcomment" name="subcomment" cols="50" rows="4">Submit comment</textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="reply" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Here we have the replies to the comment above-->
        <ul class="replies">
            <li class="clicktoviewreplies">Show/hide replies</li>
            <div class="replies-wrap">
                <div class="commentator-pic"></div>
                <div class="comment">Replies show here</div>
                <!--This is the position of the edit form-->
                <div class="edit-form">
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                        <textarea class="subcomment" name="subcomment" cols="50" rows="4">Edit reply</textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!--These are the main comment buttons or controllers-->
                <button class="edit-comment">Edit</button>
                <button class="reply">Reply</button>
                <button>Delete</button>
                <!--This is the position of the reply form-->
                <div class="reply-to-comment">
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                        <textarea class="subcomment" name="subcomment" cols="50" rows="4">Submit reply</textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="reply" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To make things easier, follow this link: https://jsfiddle.net/hx9mvdjg/8/

Comment: Check this snippet...https://jsfiddle.net/qo8jsxyw/ Is it want you want?

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this is not what I want to. What I need is that everytime I click on the ".edit-comment" button, the ".comment" div is replaced with the ".edit-form" div. It's like an overlapping effect, but not exactly an overlapping. It's a replacement of elements. The texts "Comments show here" and "Replies show here" should disappear/hide and the edit form (".edit-form" div) should show instead. Got it? Thank you

Comment: The problem is that I have two lists, the one inside another and I think something should or could be done in the third "paragraph" of the jQuery script. You can even see that this is repeated (.edit-comment click function), because I wanted to write them twice and separatedly, although I believe it's unnecessary. But this is not the main issue.

Comment: Re-read my question and try to do the proceedings I said, and you will understand what I mean to.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue once and for all:

```
//$(document).on('click' , '.edit-comment' , function(){
  $('.edit-comment').click(function(){
      var closestDiv = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent() 
     if ($(".edit-form").css("display") == "block") {
         closestDiv.find('.comment').hide();
         $('.comment').not(closestDiv.find('.comment')).css("display","block");
     }else{
        closestDiv.find('.comment').toggle();
        $('.comment').not(closestDiv.find('.comment')).css("display","block");
    }
  });
```

Get your whole code and just replace this "paragraph", as you said yourself, with the last one you have in your snippet and paste it in your "jsfiddle" and test it, please. Then, tell me if it's all you need.

Comment: Amazing. That's what I want, fellas! Thank you! You're the king of codes! I just don't understand why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Use the replaceWith() in jquery.

Comment: I tried to, but it hasn't worked out. It makes things even more complicated.